# Show a specific image in dark mode on GMAIL

Tags: css, email, gmail, darkmode

I would like to know if there is a solution to display a specific image in dark mode on GMAIL (and hide an image in light mode). I tried by applying the guide https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/ (I saw that `@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark) was not supported by GMAIL)`, but it doesn't work for GMAIL.
Thanks.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/19110624/hrks did you get any solution on this front?

Comment: Always not, thanks